# Powershell printing global variable to the log file after transcript is stopped

Tags: powershell

I am running simple application where I start transcript from one file, continue it using `-Append` option in another file and then end it.

Everything works fine, it logs everything, the only problem is it puts these two lines also in the log file by itself

```
PS>$global:?
True
```

right before the end transcript lines

```
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript end
End time: 20210507200412
**********************
```

Any idea what could be the reason?

Comment: Could you please show your script of Starting, Appending, and Stopping the transcript?

Answer (score 1):

Im not familiar with the syntax, but the statement `$global:?` does indeed evaluate to $true, as to why your code is emitting `$global:?` i cant say.

Ive just tested the following code under PowerShell 5(Windows/ ISE) and 7(Ubuntu WSL Powershell Core) and i dont get the same output as you so i suspect something in your code is outputting `$global:?` which results in the 2 lines in question? (it could something in your profile etc not necessarily in the code your looking at)

If you run the below sample do you still see the unexpected lines in the output?

```
$filename = "./transcript-test.log";

Start-Transcript -Path $filename
Write-Host "This is me writing some stuff to the screen..."
Stop-Transcript

Start-Transcript -Path $filename -Append
Write-Host "Writing more stuff to the console after reopening/appending transcript"
Stop-Transcript

Get-Content $filename
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you do a Stop-Transcript before your script ends.